# Window wont open when when i import my other script

Tags: python, pyserial, pysimplegui

GUI script to make a window:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from Communication import Data




sg.theme('DarkAmber')   # Add a touch of color
# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [  [sg.Text('Voltage', key='-text-')],
            [sg.Button('Something cool...'), sg.Button('Close')] ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=10)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Close': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    window['-text-'].update(Data)

window.close()
```

Communication script to communicate through serial with an arduino:

```
import serial

arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=.1)

global Data
while 1==1:
    rawData = arduino.readline()
    rawData = rawData.decode()
    if(rawData == ''):
        rawData = ''
    else:
        Data = rawData
        print(Data)
```

The problem that I'm having is both scripts work on their own but when i try to import communication, the GUI script does absolutely nothing.

Comment: `from Communication import Data` will execute your Communication script first, then it will stay in the while loop `while 1==1` which without break statement to end the loop.

Comment: @JasonYang Ahhh okay, that makes sense thank you